# Is it normal for a computer to have a long list of things running in Event Trace Sessions when it comes back from repair?

Tags: windows-8.1, remote, performance-monitor

I sent my Windows 8.1 laptop to the manufacturer for repair and it came back with this list of items running in the Event Trace Sessions:

1. Circular Kernel Context Logger
2. AITEventLog
3. Audio
4. Muroc System Trace
5. DiagLog
6. EventLog-Application
7. EventLog-Microsoft-Windows-WorkFolders-WHC
8. EventLog-System
9. FamilySafetyAOT
10. LwtNetLog
11. NtfsLog
12. SQMLogger
13. UBPM
14. WdiContextLog
15. MpWppTracing
16. DiagTrack-Listener

I'm having trouble finding a simple explanation of what each of these things do and why they are running on my computer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Did you confirm none of these items were listed before you sent your computer in for repair?  Or are you just now noticing them and assuming they were added while it was out for repair?

Comment: I'm just now noticing them, but I think it must be normal. I just installed Windows 10 on a virtual machine on my laptop so I checked Event Tracing and there's a bunch a stuff running

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is normal. [Since Vista the Eventlog is based on Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1aa1350-41a0-4490-9ae3-9b4520aeb9d4/faq-common-questions-for-etw-and-windows-event-log?forum=etw), so you have a lot of Event Trace Sessions running all the time.

> Beginning with Windows Vista, Windows Event Log is built on top of ETW
>   technology. Windows Event Log provides a centralized repository for
>   events which is, in general, always enabled and stored on disk.
>   Windows Event Log lets you subscribe to events using queries to either
>   local or remote machines. Because Windows Event Log is built on top of
>   ETW, the events in Windows Event Log include the same rich metadata,
>   localizable message strings, and schematized (structured) data
>   payloads for easy consumption of event data.

So everything is fine and you don't need to do anything.